# Rails validation, knowing which field is invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

i had a model which works fine.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :field1, with: /\A[0-9\+\-\/\s]+\Z/, allow_nil: true
  validates_format_of :field2, with: /\A[0-9\+\-\/\s]+\Z/, allow_nil: true
end
```

some of my entries in the database are invalid. these are older entries.
i want to run a seed which find these invalid entries

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  next if product.valid?
  # 
end
```

i want to clear the attributes which are invalid. let me say, Product 1 has the value `test` in `field1` which is invalid. now i want to clear this field, and only this.

how do i find the fields which are invalid? something like `product.field1.valid?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Rails api allows you to get the error message by the key with the [`ActiveModel::Errors#get`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-get) method:

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  product.valid? # => run validation callbacks

  product.errors.messages          # => {:field1=>["cannot be nil"]}
  product.errors.get(:field1)      # => ["cannot be nil"]
  product.errors.get(:field2)      # => nil

  # `include?` and `has_key?` works too(it's aliases)
  product.errors.messages          # => {:field1=>["cannot be nil"]}
  product.errors.include?(:field1) # => true
  product.errors.include?(:field2) # => false

  # 
end
```

Comment: careful with `Product.all.each`. If you have thousands of products, that will cripple your DB/process/server, etc

Comment: OP question is not about _perfomance_. He say nothing about _thousands of products_, it all about *check errors message*, please don't swap the wheels.

Comment: I'm not _swapping the wheels_. SO is not about getting points, but about providing useful answers. I posted that comment because in my experience `Model.all.each` is dangerous.

Comment: ah great. thanks alot. thats really what i looked for. @tomave you're right, but there lower than 100 entries in the database. and its run once a time.

Answer (score 4):

Doing it is easy, but there are a couple of things to keep in mind about performance:

1. you **don't** want to just load all your products in memory, and iterate over them,
2. if possible, you should not try to update them one by one.

This might be an acceptable solution:

```
invalid_ids = []

Product.find_each(batch_size: 200) do |product|
  if !product.valid?
    if product.errors.include?(:field_1)
      invalid_ids << product.id
    end
  end
end

Product.where(id: invalid_ids).update_all(field_1: nil)
```

Comment: thats also a good solution, but i really have to update one by once because i had to clear `field1` or `field2` or/and `field3` so i marked the other once as answer

Answer (score 0):

you can check and validate the model and its attribute using [valid?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Validations/valid%3F) and can also check for [errors](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors)

```
Product.all.each do |product|
 if  !product.valid? and !product.errors[field1].blank?
    ##do something if product is not valid and there is error in attribute that you may want to check
 end
end
```